# From Visual Studio, unable to publish to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Using this [Official Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs?view=vs-2017). I have work Azure account that I can successfully login. The account allows $150 per month of which I have $93 left.

But, as instructed in `Publish to Azure App Service` section of the tutorial, when I select `Azure App Service` as the Publish Target on the wizard, it takes me to following screen where I sign in as my work Azure account. But it does nothing after I login, and the `Next` button stayed grey. When I click on `can't access account` button and fill in requested info, I get the next screen (also shown in the image below). I, then first successfully logged in to my Azure account from outside of `VS2017` and then tried the above process again but still the same issue:

**UPDATE**

Moreover, I just deployed the same app using [this Official Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) that is `not` using `Visual Studio`. **But I want to able** to deploy it using `VS2017` as I create projects using `VS2017` only.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have rights to publish to the subscription? Can you allocate assets via the portal?

Comment: You should try to login into Azure Portal Via a browser and see you can successfully able to create a WebApp there

Comment: @Jayendran You may have missed the last sentence of my post above where I have mentioned that I had also tried what you have suggested.

Comment: @Josh I have published website to Azure Web App Service in my plan. In fact I completed an online lab `Deploy and Manage Azure App Service` using my same Azure account where I published a website, as well.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a MS acct and Org acct with the same email address and that you have the wrong profile configured in VS?

Comment: @Josh I've an MS acct, say, `myName@hotmail.com` that shows on the upper right corner of `VS2017`. Then I have org acct (that I use for Azure login), say, `myDiffOrgID@myOrgName.com`. When I loin to Azure using a separate browser using org acct, it first takes me to a different dialog box saying `Taking you to your organization's sign-in page...` where I login using my org acct and successfully enter Azure Portal where I can create all sorts of stuff etc. But if I try to login to `VS2017` using org acct it says such an MS acct does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the identity (MS acct) which you are logged into VS2017 with. You want to be sure that you are logged in to VS with the account which has rights to the subscription where you are trying to publish. Assuming that's your org account:

Click on your profile in the upper right corner and choose Account Settings. The window that pops up has a link to Add an account. You'll want to add your org account here. Now VS has the proper creds to publish to your subscription.

To verify that the creds are working, use the menu item View -> Cloud Explorer. You should see the other assets you've created in the target subscription.